# Generate a set of random numbers where the absolute value of the difference between every two numbers is greater than a given threshold

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to generate a set of random numbers in a given interval, where the absolute value of the difference between every two numbers is greater than a given threshold.

I have tried `random.sample(range(1, 5), 3)`, but I want to get a set of float numbers.

E.g. The given threshold is `1.0`.

Thus, `[1.2, -0.9, 2.5]` is right and `[1.2, 0.9, 2.5]` is wrong, because `abs(1.2 - 0.9) < 1.0`.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want, thanks in advance！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your example:

```py
import random
import numpy as np

threshold = 1
interval = [1, 5]
numbers_to_generate = 3
generate_random_number = lambda interval=interval: interval[1] - np.random.random() * abs(interval[1] - interval[0])
results = [generate_random_number()]

for _ in range(numbers_to_generate - 1):
    while (number := generate_random_number()):
        if all(abs(number - val) > threshold for val in results):
            break
    results.append(number)
print(results)  # [1.4382328683652945, 3.3028479417473693, 4.59829694731385]
```

However, with bad parameters (e.g. `interval = [1, 3]`, `threshold = 2`, `numbers_to_generate = 3`) or bad luck it can go on forever.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learn a lot from your answer!